# Can I tell from javascript whether my page was hard refreshed?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I've given up on this, but I thought I'd post here out of curiosity.

What I call a "hard refresh" is the <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+F5</kbd> that you do during development to see your changes.

This causes the browser to add a `Cache-Control: max-age=0` header to the request *and* "child" requests like images and scripts, etc.

If you're doing your job, you'll get a `304` on everything but the resource that's changed.  (Okay, well, see comments.  This is assuming that other validators are sent based on browser caches.)

So far, so good.

**The problem** is that I'm not loading scripts directly from the page, but through a `load.js`, and the browsers are inconsistent about whether they include that `Cache-Control` header on those requests.  Chrome doesn't do it at all, and Firefox seems to stop in the middle of a series.

Since I can't access the headers of the current request, there's no way to know whether that header should be included or not.

The result is that when I change a script (other than `load.js`), a hard refresh does not reliably work, and I have to, e.g., clear the browser cache (which is a bit heavy-handed).

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I don't have a fully formed answer, but is there anything you could do with timing? E.g. server a dummy static file with a delay (e.g. php with `usleep(1000)`) and see how quickly it loads. If it loaded in < 100ms then you know it was cached. If not, then you know to tell load.js to forcibly load stuff.

Comment: If you're responding to a request with `Cache-control: max-age=0` by telling me to use the cache, you're *not* doing your job.  According to the spec, that header must be obeyed.

Comment: @Pointy, okay, fair enough.  I do still use cached copies even when `max-age=0`, so yes, that breaks the spec.  I think this is a common way to avoid unnecessary load.  Basically I use it as a way to force revalidation (in cases where even revalidation can be expensive), and not regeneration.

Comment: Well, you're making some big assumptions about what the client is, which may be OK for your content/site/app. A client may not *have* a cached copy of a resource being requested.

Comment: @Pointy, right, what I mean is that I prioritize other validators when they are included with `max-age=0`, and the browser sends all of these when they are available.  (As does IIS for static content.)  I *also* use server-side caches for generated content even when `max-age=0`, if I determine that the cache is up-to-date with respect to its sources.  In those cases of course I send a `200` and a full response.  So maybe that doesn't break the spec.

Comment: OK well it sounds like you've thought about this a lot more than I have anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot detect a hard refresh from JavaScript (there is no access to the headers for the currently loaded page).

However, the server *can* tell from the request headers if this is a hard refresh, so there's the option of cooperating. For example the server can include a custom `<meta>` tag in the response or add a special class to `<body>` and your script will then have access to this information.

Once `load.js` detects a hard refresh it can then propagate it to the dependent scripts by e.g. attaching a URL parameter to the requests (think `"?t=" + timestamp`).

Comment: Jon, thanks for the reply.  I thought about this, but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of caching on the page itself?  i.e., if the parent page hasn't changed, then it should return a `304`.  Now that you mention it, though, it would be reasonable to do this in the loader script itself, since it's small.  That is, always return a value that indicates whether or not the cache was bypassed.  I doubt I'd do this in practice, though, since the issue only affects me.

Comment: @harpo: The problem with JavaScript is that it has no notion of a 304. It begins executing in the context of a webpage, but it doesn't know how either itself or the page got there. Hence the suggestion of putting something *inside* the page.

Comment: Jon, understood.  It's a creative solution, but I think the cost of breaking caching on the page doesn't outweigh the benefit of this use case.  I say "breaking caching" because as I understand it the page would now have a dependency on the request headers, regardless of its content.

Comment: @harpo: I 'm not sure how you define "dependency" here. The server can look at the `Cache-Control` header and if it smells a hard refresh based on that it does what it does. How would caching break, assuming you don't get false positives?

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense now, after comments from Pointy.  Yes, technically the server is supposed to regenerate in that case anyway (so you'd have a chance to include the `meta` tag).  But in practice, I don't regenerate full pages because of `max-age`.

Comment: I don't think, that this works as expected. In particular, the "hard reloaded" page might be cached itself in one of the many ways, that browsers utilize caches, and thus might still indicate a hard reload, when it is actually not the case.

Answer (score -3):

You could try checking localStorage. Set a localStorage variable and check it. If it's there, it's not a hard refresh, otherwise, it is a hard refresh.

Comment: Doesn't the browser prompt when you try to use this, though?  Something like "This web site would like to store data on your computer."

Comment: localStorage persists regardless of how the page was loaded (new/hard/soft reload)